# intl extension should be available symfony

Tags: php, symfony

Right now if I go to http://localhost:8000/config.php it tells me : Install and enable the intl extension (used for validators).

So what I did was:

Checked `/etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini` file which had `;extension=php_intl.dll`

Installed `symfony/intl` in `composer.json`

And still get the recommendation to install and enable intl extension.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

make sure that you've activated the `extension=php_intl.dll` in :

```
/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini
//           ^^^^^^^
```

and the other thing, enable your extension by **uncomment** your extension by removing the *semi-colon*

> #### [Loading an extension](http://php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.windows.php#install.pecl.windows.loading)
>
> The most common way to load a PHP extension is to include it in your
>   php.ini configuration file. Please note that many extensions are
>   already present in your php.ini and that you only need to remove the
>   semicolon to activate them.
>
> `;extension=php_extname.dll`
>
> `extension=php_extname.dll`

after that, you will need to restart your apache2

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

---

### Update (leave the part above away) :-

you are seems to be using linux based system specially `debian/ubuntu` dist, and trying to activate php extension using the `Windows OS` style

to install php intl in debian/ubuntu:

for php 5 :

```
sudo apt-get install php5-intl
```

and for php 7 :

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-intl
```

then simply enable your extension by :

```
sudo php5enmod intl
```

or for php7 :

```
sudo phpenmod intl
```

then restart your apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: @JustinTime: To clarify why it needs to be `/apache2/` and not `/cli/`: `/cli/` is for the CLI PHP program (command line interface) and `/apache2/` is for the PHP plugin used by Apache (webserver).

Comment: ah, I did that and now when i start my server I get the error : PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_intl.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/php_intl.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Now I get a warning with intl ICU version installed on your system is outdated (55.1) and does not match the ICU data bundled with Symfony (58.2). I think it works now thank you and @TomUdding very much!

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the semicolon from `;extension=php_intl.dll`. As it is now; it is commented out and will be ignored. That means it won't enable `php_intl.dll` as extension.

You can check [this example](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php#example-37) (php.ini documentation) for more information.

Comment: @JustinTime Have you restarted your installation?